# Finding the least costly cycle on a graph where at least one node out of multiple node subsets must be met and each edge has a cost

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, traversal

I have a group of nodes and edges connecting these nodes, each edge has a cost to traverse. All of these nodes are put into their subsets and a cycle must be found for the lowest cost to visit at least one node in each of these subsets. You can imagine this as each node is a different position on an island chain and each subset is an island. You start at one position and need to visit every island and then return to where you started for the lowest cost. You don't get to decide where you start, that is pre-chosen for you. I want to eventually create a program to run this and there are around 30 nodes and 6 subsets. Does anyone know of a fairly efficient algorithm that can complete what I need in a reasonable amount of time on a pretty nice computer. If you don't know a very efficient algorithm I would still love to hear it anyway just in case it might help.

I have tried just guessing and checking but it takes very long time and I would like to be able to dynamically change the weights of the edges and quickly get a new route.

Edit: To clarify you should not assume the edges between the islands are always greater than those within them. Also all nodes are connected by edges to all other nodes. This is a practical problem, and don't read to deap into the island analogy. Just trying to visualize it. Those are all the rules, you can visit an island as many time as you like and you can visit a node as many times as you like.

Comment: This looks like a variant of the travelling salesman problem

Comment: If this is a practical problem, just use a greedy algorithm and take the hit that it might not be optimal. If it's an academic problem such that optimality is non-negotiable, then you'll need to find or develop an algorithm for this. I can't be sure without trying it, but I don't think brute-forcing for optimal solutions is going to work well for the general case, even limited to 30 nodes and 6 subsets.  Have a go at coding a TSP algorithm and see if it inspires you with ways to tackle this variant.

Comment: When you say 'each node is a different position on an island chain and each subset is an island', do you mean they are arranged linearly? So, all points in the i-1th island are further from all points in i+1th island than all points in ith island? If so, that is an important fact you should clarify, or am I reading too much into your 'island chain' description?

Comment: My understanding is that you are given a *complete graph* (an undirected graph that has an edge between every pair of nodes) with specified origin and destination nodes, a cost associated with each edge and a partitioning of the nodes into subsets. The objective is to find a minimum-cost path from origin to destination that passes through all of the subsets of nodes (i.e., the path includes at least one node from each subset). Is that correct?

Comment: I just realized there was a problem with my answer: the existence of negative cycles (cycles for which the sum of the costs of the edges is negative). Shortest path algorithms cannot be used in the presence of negative cycles. I therefore have deleted my answer.

Comment: Is a solution that visits the same color multiple times okay? What about a solution that visits the same node multiple times? Or do you need a solution with one node per color?

Comment: Is there a restriction on how many times any one node can be visited?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new graph that has one vertex for each island.  Link every vertex, if the islands they represent are linked, with a link of the least cost of the links between them in the original.  Apply a travelling saleaman algorithm to the new graph.  ( There are lots of TSP algorithms and graph theory libraries that implement them.  With so few nodes ( just 6 ), you do not need an efficient one - brute force search will likely take less than a second for such a small graph )

Now you have the slightly tricky problem to identify the real vertices to be used for each island.  Again, no need to be clever, just try all possibilities, and select the one or two nodes in each island that give the cheapest result.

This answer is likely to offend the computer scientists among us.  However, since you have indicated this is a real world problem, not an academic exercise, and because this is supposed to be programming help site ( there are other sites for computer scientists ) I believe that a quick and dirty method that could be implemented in an afternoon is more useful than hunting around for complicated algorithms that will take days to understand and implement.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to give the best solution, and under certain inputs it gives an arbitrarily bad solution (by having the cost of connecting same-set nodes on the optimal collapsed cycle be arbitrarily higher than some different slightly-less-optimal collapsed cycle).

Comment: As far as I can understand this is basically find the best route between the islands and than the best route within them. I worry that this won't be the most efficient route because it might be more efficient to visit an island and then immediately leave it instead of jumping around within. If you imagine the costs of each edge as the distance that must be traveled than this always makes more sense because the shortest path from a to b is straight, infact that is how the costs are applied in my application. I would also like to clarify that all of the vertices are connected by edges.

Comment: "might be more efficient to visit an island and then immediately leave it"  This will ALWAYS be more efficient if "all of the vertices are connected by edges" in which case there never is any reason to "jump around".  The 2nd stage of the algorithm will pick the best vertex in each island to use for a flying visit

Comment: Note: I am assuming that the distances between vertices in an island are always less than the distances between islands.

Comment: "Note: I am assuming that the distances between vertices in an island are always less than the distances between islands." This is a false assumption.

Comment: Well, that is a very unexpected detail.  I think you should mention it in your question.  It makes a huge difference to the level of difficulty.